# How do I turn a list in a .txt file into a list in a python file?

Tags: python

I have a .txt file which contains 'lists'

```
3
[2,4,6,7]
[9,11,10,12,13]
```

And when I do `num_list = open("file.txt").read().splitlines()`
then print it, my result is

```
['3','[2,4,6,7]','[9,11,10,12,13]']
```

How can I change it to make my result

```
[3, [2,4,6,7], [9,11,10,12,13]]
```

EDIT:
I tried this, and it's close

```
for i in num_list:
    for j in i:
        j.split(" ")
        list(j)
        print(j)
```

but now the output is

```
['2', '135', '2467']
```

Comment: thank you for pointing out that there is a similar question but can i please ask why you go out of your way to search for a duplicate?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could use `literal_eval`:

```
import ast
with open('file.txt') as f:
    lists = [ast.literal_eval(line) for line in f]
print(lists)
```

prints

```
[3, [2, 4, 6, 7], [9, 11, 10, 12, 13]]
```